# How to set a different java file as launcher

Tags: android

I am new to android and i have created a class in my android project other than the default MainActivity class and i want to start my project with that file. Here is what i added to my manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.surfaceview.SurfaceViewExample"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SURFACEVIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And the class that i created:

```
public class SurfaceViewExample extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

OurView v;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v=new OurView(this);
    setContentView(v);
    v.setOnTouchListener(this);
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    v.pause();
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    v.resume();
}



public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread t = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean isItOK=false;

    public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder=getHolder();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isItOK){
            if(holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                continue;
            }

            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawARGB(255, 155, 155, 10);//canvas backgroundu boyama
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

    }

    public void pause(){ //pause the thread
        isItOK=false;
        while(true){
            try{
                t.join();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;              
        }
        t=null;
    }

    public void resume(){ //resume the thread
        isItOK=true;
        t=new Thread(this); //this parameter means use this run method
                            //which is inside that class
        t.start();
    }


}



@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    return false;
}

}
```

But the application does not start. I think the problem might be in that line inside the intent filter:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SURFACEVIEW" />
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @HugoHidekiYamashita should i add it inside the intent filter? I did that but did not work

Comment: actually i replaced <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  with <action android:name="android.intent.action.SURFACEVIEW" />

Comment: Yes, so un-replace it. The name of the action is `MAIN` whatever your class is called.

Comment: thank you all for the answer works

Comment: @panpa usually, the launchers send the MAIN action and the LAUNCHER category to launch applications, that's why replacing the MAIN action caused your application not to be launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your manifest with the following code for your activity. This should now launch your activity.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.surfaceview.SurfaceViewExample"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I hope this helps.